# SQL Server: загрузка CSV в таблицу

Tags: sql-server, csv

Как CSV файл, в котором есть строка с заголовками столбцов, и несколько тысяч строк с данными, загрузить в таблицу в SQL Server? Возможна ли загрузка CSV, если очередность столбцов в таблице в базе данных не совпадает с очередностью в CSV?

CSV примерно такой

```
Id,      ParentId,   CreationDate
"12345", "",         "2016-01-01 11:11:11"
... (остальные несколько тысяч строк)
```

Answer (score 3):

Поля таблицы соответствуют столбцам вашего csv-файла?

Есть различные графические клиенты предоставляющие возможность импортировать данные из различных форматов.

Программа `HeidiSQL` дает вам графический интерфейс для построения команды `LOAD DATA`. Позже, вы можете использовать её повторно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы открыть этот диалог для импорта файла, выберите `Tools > Import CSV file`:

К сожалению не хватает репутации, для добавления всех ссылок и изображений. Надеюсь эта информация вам поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать загрузку с помощью команды `bulk insert` с опцией `firstrow = 2`. Также можно загрузить данные во временную таблицу, подготовить их как надо, а затем из временной таблицы сделать вставку в нужную таблицу, задав нужный порядок столбцов.

Создаём промежуточную временную таблицу (здесь порядок столбцов как в .csv файле):

```
create table #import
(
    Id varchar(100),
    ParentId varchar(100),
    CreationDate varchar(100)
)
```

Импортируем данные:

```
bulk insert #import
from 'd:\Temp\test.csv'
with
(
    firstrow = 2,
    fieldterminator = ',',
    rowterminator = '\n',
    tablock
)
```

Подготовка данных:

```
update #import
set
    Id = ltrim(rtrim(Id)),
    ParentId = ltrim(rtrim(ParentId)),
    CreationDate = ltrim(rtrim(CreationDate))

update #import
set
    Id = replace(Id,'"', ''),
    ParentId = replace(ParentId,'"', ''),
    CreationDate = replace(CreationDate,'"', '')
```

Вставка данных в постоянную таблицу (вставляем в соответствующие столбцы как нам надо):

```
insert into TableName (Id, ParentId, CreationDate)
select
    cast(Id as int),
    cast(nullif(ParentId, '') as int),
    convert(datetime, CreationDate, 120)
from #import
```

Последние два этапа можно объединить в один запрос.